# Vertex attributes in bipartite network igraph

Tags: r, attributes, igraph, bipartite

Firstly I'm very new to R so apologies if this is a simple question.

I have a .csv with an edge network of groups, people associated with them and some attributes of both the people and groups

e.g.

> Group Person  PersonGame  GroupGame
>   A       Jane Doe    Snooker  Tennis
>   B      John Doe     Football Football
>   A       Bill
>   Smith Tennis  Tennis
>   B      Francis Underwood    Football Football
>  
>   A    Francis Underwood    Football Tennis

I've drawn a bipartite network:

```
df <- read.csv("file.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
df.network <- graph.data.frame(df, directed = F)
V(df.network)$type <- bipartite.mapping(df.network)$type
```

Currently I've coloured the Group and Person vertexes differently as follows:

```
V(df.network)$color <- ifelse(V(df.network)$type, "grey", "orange")
```

what I really want to do though is colour the Person vertexes differently depending on the "Person Game" field, but this doesn't seem to be an attribute that I can access for a Vertex, only an Edge. So this works to colour the edges:

```
E(df.network)$color <- ifelse(E(df.network)$PersonGame=='Snooker', 
 "red", ifelse(E(df.network)$PersonGame=='Football', "blue", "orange"))
```

but it doesn't work if I apply to vertexes instead of edge as I can't get the PersonGame attribute to apply to a vertex.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend transferring the games to the nodes.
Since some nodes are Groups and others are Persons,
I will just call it Game (rather than PersonGame 
and GroupGame), but I will transfer the PersonGames
to the Persons and the GroupGames to the Groups.

```
PA = unique(cbind(ends(df.network, E(df.network))[,2], E(df.network)$PersonGame))
GA = unique(cbind(ends(df.network, E(df.network))[,1], E(df.network)$GroupGame))

V(df.network)$Game = ""
V(df.network)[PA[,1]]$Game = PA[,2]
V(df.network)[GA[,1]]$Game = GA[,2]
```

Now, every node has a Game. We can modify your statement that 
created an edge color to create a vertex color. I added a line 
to color the Groups differently

```
V(df.network)$color <- ifelse(V(df.network)$Game=='Snooker', 
 "red", ifelse(V(df.network)$Game=='Football', "blue", "orange"))
V(df.network)[!V(df.network)$type]$color = "lightgray"
```

Now we can plot with node colors.

```
LO = layout_as_bipartite(df.network)
plot(df.network, layout=LO)
```

[image: Network with colored nodes]